# How to send String[] As value of HashMap to REST

Tags: java, android, api, rest, magento

I am trying to send a HashMap to Magento REST API From Android. The rest contain a array element as showing below.

```
[{
    "id": "26",
    "label": "",
    "position": "1",
    "exclude": "0",
    "url": "http:\/\/localhost\/magento\/media\/catalog\/product\/6\/1\/61UROlGlryL._UL1500_.jpg_20.jpg",
    "types": []
}]
```

I tried to send the data using `HttpPost` As showing below.

```
Map < String, String > productimages = new HashMap < String, String > ();

productimages.put("file_mime_type", mime);
productimages.put("file_content", encodedImage);
productimages.put("file_name", pictureName);

String[] datas = {
  "image", "small_image", "thumbnail"
};
productimages.put("types", datas.toString());
Gson gson = new Gson();
String productimages_json = gson.toJson(productimages);
StringEntity productimages_entity = new StringEntity(productimages_json, HTTP.UTF_8);
HttpPost httppost_img = new HttpPost(URL_PRODUCTS + "/6/images");
httppost_img.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
httppost_img.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httppost_img.setEntity(productimages_entity);
Log.d("inserted", "");
HttpResponse response_img = client.execute(targetHost, httppost_img, localContext);
```

All the data rather than "types":[ ] is hitting the web service. When send the data as single string like `productimages.put("types", "image");` it hit the web service Successfully But I need to send more than one value.Also I tried the following but no result.

```
Map<String,String[]> productimages = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
String[] datas = {"image","small_image","thumbnail"};
productimages.put("types", datas);
```

How I can send the String[] values with the single key to REST Web Service.Anyone please help me to solve this.

Comment: "but no result" doesn't tell us anything about what you've observed. What gets sent over the wire, and how have you observed that? Note that the code you've shown so far wouldn't even compile, specifically this line: `productimages.put("types", datas.toString);` as `toString()` is a method, not a field. How many other differences are there between the code you've shown us and your real code?

Comment: I didn't put my full code here,I just put what I tried.  'productimages.put("types", datas.toString);' line dose not shows any error. If you know tell me how to send the String[] values to Web Service.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't believe you. That line of code simply *won't* compile. You'd need `productimages.put("types", data.toString())`. Note the extra brackets. You still haven't explained to us what you've observed though...

Comment: @Jon Skeet,@ Sorry for that Now I edited My question.

Comment: Right - and have you looked at what `datas.toString()` will return? Have you tried using a `Map<String, Object>` instead?

Comment: @ Jon Skeet - sorry for the late replay, your suggestion is working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Mr:Jon Skeet suggest me I am able to send the data as object as below.

```
Map<String,Object> productimages = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            List<String> datas = new ArrayList<String>();
            datas.add("image");
            datas.add("small_image");
            datas.add("thumbnail");

productimages.put("file_mime_type", mime);
productimages.put("file_content", encodedImage);
productimages.put("file_name", pictureName);

productimages.put("types", datas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for (int i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
    productimages.put("types[" + Integer.toString(i) + "]", datas[i]);
}
```

Comment: I am really sorry to say this is not working for me.

Comment: @RemeesMSyde can you describe the problem you have encountered with this code?

Comment: The string[] value passed is not getting in the response when I try to get the response.All Other values passed is got in response properly.